# Resolving I correctly in a SAS Iterative Do Loop

Tags: sas, sas-macro, do-loops

I'm having problems understanding how the Index variable (i) is applied/resolved inside a do loop. I have a very simple SQL macro-

*Note - The macro is called after a preceding `proc sql noprint;` as well as the `quit;` statement outside of the macro.

```
%macro psql(into,date);
   select count(distinct task) into: &into
   from source
   where c_date between &start and &date;
%mend psql;
```

The macro is called via - `%psql(count10,&date10);`

*Note - Macro variables `&date10-&date20` have all been previously defined. This works perfectly-the macro var `&count10` is created, using the date value from `&date10-&date20` for each line calling the `%psql` macro with its respective parameters.

As always, I have been asked to extend this to many more dates, so listing the `%psql` macro is going to be repetitive.

Assuming a do loop would be most efficient, I attempted the following in order to use the index(i) to create my variables, instead of many macro calls (each holding new macro parameters):

```
%macro doloop;
   %do i=10 %to 20;
      proc sql noprint;
         select count(distinct task) into: count&i
         from source
         where c_date between &start and &date&i;
      quit;
   %end;
%mend doloop;
```

My attempt to use (I) in order to create the `&count` macro variables and reference the `&date` parameter does not seem to resolve WITH the actual macro vars being created/referenced, but the varaiable (I) itself seems to resolve correctly during iterations -

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 10
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable START resolves to    20429
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DATE resolves to    20435
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 10

SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 11
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable START resolves to    20429
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DATE resolves to    20435
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 11
```

Does the issue involve my attempting to use (I) in order to "call" an existing macro var, and using (I) to create a macro variable at the same time? How can I reference (I) in order to create my &count variables (&count10-&count....) while using the already existing date variables(&date10-&date....) ?

Comment: Thinking here...does it make sense to just call the date variables using a statice date + (I) instead of having predefined date macro variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about the differences between `count&i`, `&date&i`, and `&&date&i`.

`count&i` will resolve to COUNT10. And the way your SQL code is written this will be used as the name of the macro variable that receives the count.

`&date&i` will depend on the value of the `DATE` macro variable. If the macro variable `DATE` has the value `20435` then your SQL code will be using the value `2043510`, which is in the year 7554, in your date comparison

`&&date&i` will first reduce to `&date10` and then further resolve to the value of the macro variable `DATE10`.  I think this is what you want to use in your SQL code.

Here is an example with `SYMBOLGEN` turned on.

```
105  %let date10=SOME DATE VALUE;
106  %let date=ANOTHER DATE VALUE;
107  %let i=10;
108  options symbolgen;
109  %put count&i;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 10
count10
110  %put &date&i;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DATE resolves to ANOTHER DATE VALUE
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 10
ANOTHER DATE VALUE10
111  %put &&date&i;
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 10
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DATE10 resolves to SOME DATE VALUE
SOME DATE VALUE
```

Comment: I believe you are correct, but I cannot confirm this because I do not understand the way multiple "&" resolve, although I have seen the post (by Joe I believe) many times. The last statement is exactly what I want...the first iteration to produce the macro var COUNT10 using the date macro var of &DATE10.

Comment: You can use SYMBOLGEN to watch it in action. `%let date10=SOME DATE VALUE;%let i=10;options symbolgen;%put &&date&i;`

Comment: Not sure If I can do this, but can I re-reference this post? This solution worked fine yesterday when the updates were made. Now today, the macro vars Count10-count... will not resolve correctly...

Comment: If you are using a macro then make sure to either define the macro variables first or add a `%GLOBAL` statement to your macro. Otherwise the COUNTxxx macro variables generated by PROC SQL will be local to the macro and disappear when the macro ends.  Most likely yesterday you had already defined them so the macro used the existing macro variables instead of creating new local ones.

Comment: AHHH! duh! You are correct! In addition, I tried to shorten the list of global vars by using the %global cured:; - but it seems that it doesn't like the ":" as it usually serves as a shortcut for me. Was hoping this would save me from listing all variables created...seems not. Any shortcuts to listing these macro vars as global, or am I stuck typing out 15~ macro vars.

Comment: Damnit... Not sure why I couldn't arrive to that...but thanks for the help on this (and above)!